# Returning result from jQuery's .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda, each

My "stack" is totally overflow, so I need a help :)

I trying to get all values from FORM and save them to associative array. Here is a code:

```
var dat = [];
$('form[name=' + form.name + '] input[name], form[name=' + form.name + '] select[name], form[name=' + form.name + '] textarea[name]').each(function(i,el) {
   dat[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

I am waiting for all values become in dat after this piece of code, but it looks like dat is internal variable of .each() lambda function, so it is unavailable after .each() is completed.

How to return resulting dat[] from the cycle ?

Comment: Can't you just serialise the form with $("#formId").Serialize();

Comment: looks like an object to me... try `var dat = {};` instead of `var dat = [];`

Comment: Question, why do you need this? Can you not just use jQuery's serialize() (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to get all information from the form?

Comment: Is your selector returning the Form elements you expect? No data in, no values out...

Comment: RubbleFord, Alex - I am using same code to extract data from DOM children, so parent element can be not only FORM, but also DIV for example.

Comment: OMG, guys, I am fool. There must be curly braces of course! Thanks, Joseph!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function() getFormData(){
    var dat = {};

    $('form[name=' + form.name + ']').find('input[name], select[name], textarea[name]').each(function(i,el) {
       dat[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    return dat;
}
```

This function will return a json object containing all the form elements name/value pair specified in the selector.